# How much did banks profit from quantitative easing over a scenario where the Federal Reserve would have simply brought Treasury bonds directly?

Tags: united-states, federal-reserve

When the US Federal Reserve did quantitative easing the Federal Reserve had multiple choices to go about it.
They could have simply brought government bonds and thus benefit the US Treasury. Instead of doing that they brought other assets as well.

How much did banks and other actors profit from the buying of other assets over a scenario where the Federal Reserve would have channeled all newly introduced money into treasury bills?

Comment: It's a good question but offtopic here imho. Maybe Quant.SE?

Comment: @user4012: Why is it offtopic? It's about a political decision to allocate huge amounts of money.

Comment: Federal Reserve decisions are (supposed to be) apolitical. Effects of their decisions on private actors are most certainly not a question of politics but finance

Comment: Because this is predominantly an economic question. The Fed is one of the least political institutions in the US

Comment: @user4012 : The fact that someone pretends their decisions are apolitical doesn't mean that there aren't political implications of how a public instituation directs large sums of money.

Comment: @Christian - the problem is that those implications are purely finance related. Not something a politics expert can asnwer.

Comment: Question as is might not be worded as well as it could be (to emphasize the political aspect), but I think it's a stretch to suggest any allocation of public money as enormous as the federal reserve could be considered apolitical.  The machinations of central banks has been firmly in the realm of politics since Andrew Jackson's time.

Comment: @user4012 : It depends a bit of what you mean with "politics-expert". If you think it's about knowing about Trumps latest tweet and the reactions of various people to that tweet than it doesn't matter. If you think being a politics expert is about knowing about political power, than understanding government policy about how trillions are following matters a great deal.

Comment: @grovkin : By that logic a question about whether the rich or the poor profit from Trumps tax plan also wouldn't be about politics?

Comment: @grovkin : Both issues are about the monetary effects of who profits from government policy.

Comment: @user4012 I think this question should be ontopic here. Economic policies and analysis is part of politics too.